# where to put modal login in html5

Tags: html, css

i am entirely new to web development. i have an index page and a login page. i want to incorporate the login in the index page as a modal login page. please how would i do it.

---

here are the codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Ascend &mdash; be loved</title>
</head>

<body>


<div id="mypage">
<header id="myheader" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-inner">
            <h1><a href="#">Ascend<span>.</span></a></h1>
            <nav role="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>



                    <!-- i want to inert the modal login button here-->

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div>
```

Here is the sample form i want to convert to modal form. the button to call the form should be placed on the header eg "login here"
and this form should be placed within the html5 codes such that when i click the "login here" button the modal form below will appear.

```
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Modal Box</h2>
    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of 
CSS3.</p>
    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows 
when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put modal wherever you want. You can write it's code just below header closing tag and give it an unique id which will have `z-index` property of negative value. It will make you modal appear in front of everything.

You can read more about z-index [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Comment: i have edited the question to have a sample code of the modal form i wish to place in the index page. i want to know where exactly to place the " <a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>"   so that it will pop up the modal page when clicked. thanks